# nginx proxy_pass loads assets from root

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm sorry if this was answered in the past but I can't seem to find any answer that will work for me.

I have setup nginx on my windows machine and I'm trying to redirect some /subfolders/ to different web apps running on it.

My config is as simple as can be:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my.ip;

    location / {
        resolver 192.168.0.202;
        root   data/www;
        index  index.html;
    }

   location /plex {
   resolver 192.168.0.202;
   proxy_pass http://my.ip:32488;
   }

    location /radarr {
    resolver 192.168.0.202;
   proxy_pass http://my.ip:8787;
    }

    location /sonarr {
    resolver 192.168.0.202;
   proxy_pass http://my.ip:8989;

    }

    location /pihole {
    resolver 192.168.0.202;
   proxy_pass http://my.ip:8081/admin;

    }

  }
}
```

The loading of /subdir/ works fine, but all the assets are being loaded from / which return 404 as expected.

I have tried a lot of stuff found online but nothing worked.

Thank am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You can try `proxy_pass http://my.ip:8989$request_uri;`

Comment: still getting 404

Comment: Look at the logs to see what is the actual URL that is being loaded from

Comment: i've used the browser network console and it just loads my.ip/asset.css for example instead of my.ip/sub/asset.css

Comment: You won't be able to catch server-side things using the browser. `proxy_pass` is completely transparent to the browser, in contrast to `return 301 ...` You have to look at nginX logs (maybe even enable debug mode) AND the logs for the application which listens on ports 32488/8787/8989/8081

Answer (score 0):

Your root dir is: `root   data/www;` It's seems you've missed a forward slash "`/`". It should be like this: `root /data/www;`

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best/ most efficient way to do this but with some partial testing I think something along the lines of the below should help ? Basically checking the http referer header to re-direct it to correct location. I have read IfIsEvil on nginx site but using it for return is 100% safe. Please note I haven't tested this fully.

```
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  resolver 192.168.0.202;

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my.ip;
    root   data/www;

    location / {
      if ($http_referer ~* \/plex) {
        return 302 /plex$uri;
      }
      if ($http_referer ~* \/radarr) {
        return 302 /radarr$uri;
      }           
      index  index.html;
    }

   location /plex {
     proxy_pass http://my.ip:32488;
   }

    location /radarr {
      proxy_pass http://my.ip:8787;
    }
  }
}
```